# Can't bind change event to the file input from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a upload button that is generated through ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url:AJAX_DIR+'post_event.php',
    type:'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data:data,
    success:function(resp){
        container.html(resp);
        var upload_cover = $($.parseHTML(resp)).find('.event-upload-cover');    
        if(upload_cover.length > 0){
            console.log(upload_cover);
            upload_cover.bind('change'); //I also tried 'onchange' and it failed as well
        }   


    }
            });
```

the console gives me 
`[input#upload-cover-9151c11e05fb881d861cd45b.event-upload-cover.hdn-input, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[2], context: undefined, selector: ".event-upload-cover"]`, so I do select the file input successfully.

I have a event handler for change event for all the class event-upload-cover

```
$('.event-upload-cover').on('change',function(){
   alert('changed');
});
```

However, the event handler won't fire when the input file element returned from ajax. I can only bind change event to the element that's already loaded

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML also? Better yet a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: `upload_cover.bind('change');`, i am not very sure about this, but where's the handle function? Does it work without the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its because you create a new element and jquery object from the response. First you insert it and then you parse it again to attach the event. This creates a new element and jquery object. You want to hang on to the current reference of the element. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:AJAX_DIR+'post_event.php',
    type:'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data:data,
    success:function(resp){
        var element = $($.parseHTML(resp));
        container.append(element);
        var upload_cover = element.find('.event-upload-cover');    
        if(upload_cover.length > 0){
            console.log(upload_cover);
            upload_cover.on('change',function(){
                alert('changed');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

To delegate the event you can find the closest existing element like this:

```
$('body').on('change', '.event-upload-cover',
    function() {
        alert('changed');
    }
);
```

Comment: I did container.html(resp) before I bind the event, let me edit it to make it more clear

Comment: @KesongXie Looking at some comments above I am getting confused. Are you trying to trigger a change event or attach it? If you are trying to trigger it use the trigger method but since that object doesn't exist yet you should delegate the event on an element that exists.

Comment: I want to attach a change event instead of triggering it, and your approach seems to work when I have this upload_cover.on('change', function(){
        alert('just changed');
       });

Comment: OK cool, so you are trying to attach the event. And the issue was you attached it to an element that never got inserted into the DOM because you were double parsing it. =]

Comment: what do you mean by double parsing it?

Comment: As you  have suggested, $('body').on('change', '.event-upload-cover', function(){ alert('changed')} will yield to the correct result.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear there. I mean when you did this: container.html(resp); that parsed the html and replaced the html of container with that newly parsed html. Then when you did this: $($.parseHTML(resp)) that reparsed the html and created a jquery object. So you parsed the same html twice. Double parsed.